# Apply or not a DataTemplate on the fly

Tags: c#, xaml, datatemplate, gridcontrol

I have a grid with a column datatemplate that I'd like to apply (or not) based on a checkbox tick in it's header.

Can't figure out how to handle this though. Would there be an enabled flag somewhere?

```
<dxg:GridControl>
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn>
            <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="StatusCheck" Content="Status" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    ...
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using a third party control (`dxg:...`). Therefore, you have to look up it's documentation to be sure.

Most templated Controls have a `TemplateSelector` property for their datatemplates, where you can pass a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx).

If that is not the case, you can still put a custom Control into the header, that changes it's visualization depending on your data.

Third option is, to just set your checkboxes visibility depending on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Kai seems to be the good one. But adding what I did as well as I had already implemented differently.

The idea was to create a property in the VM, bound to the checkbox and hook it with the template. The trick was that to hook it in the grid, I had to look at an 'ancestor' through the `ElementName` that would contain the property, here `MyControl`:

```
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridColumn>
      <dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox x:Name="StatusCheck" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ShowStatusIcon, ElementName=MyControl}" Content="Show icon"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </dxg:GridColumn.HeaderTemplate>
      <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
              <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Condition ... /> <!-- Other condition that I need -->
                  <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowStatusIcon, ElementName=MyControl}" Value="True" />
                  <Condition ... /> <!-- Other condition that I needed for the template to be applied -->
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter ... /> <!-- Fall back if condition not met, ie. other data template -->
              </MultiDataTrigger>
```